# Counting grades not working

Tags: java, arrays, count

For this code, I have a grade assigned to an array of scores. I would like to count the grades (Ex: A:3 B:4 C:4 ...). When I run the program, it says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 70
    at ProcessMarks.gradeDistn(ProcessMarks.java:115)
    at ProcessMarks.main(ProcessMarks.java:38)
```

Code:

```
char[] grades = new char[testMarks.length];
getGrades(testMarks, grades);
int[] counts = gradeDistn (grades);

for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++){
    System.out.println( grades[i] + " : " + counts[i]);

public static void getGrades (int[] testMarks, char[] grades) {
    for (int i = 0; i < testMarks.length; i++) {
        if (testMarks[i] >= 90)
            grades[i] = 'A';
        else if (testMarks[i] >= 75)
            grades[i] = 'B';
        else if (testMarks[i] >= 60)
            grades[i] = 'C';
        else if (testMarks[i] >= 50)
            grades[i] = 'D';
        else if (testMarks[i] >= 45)
            grades[i] = 'E';
        else
            grades[i] = 'F';
    }
}

public static int[] gradeDistn (char[] grades){
    int[] counts = new int[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) //count the occurrences
        counts[grades[i]]++;
    return counts;
}
```

Comment: Why is the getGrades function within the for loop? Was that a mistake when you typed this into your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your gradeDistn - function.
You try to use the grade as an index of the array. But the grade is a character and what you need is a number. Java simply converts your character to a integer, so to the character's ascii code.

So this is what you can do:

```
public static int[] gradeDistn (char[] grades){
        int[] counts = new int[6];
        for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) //count the occurrences
            counts[grades[i] - 'A']++;
        return counts;

    }
```

EDIT:

The output should look something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
   char gradeAsChar = 'A' + i;
   System.out.println(gradeAsChar + ":"+ counts[i]);
}
```

Comment: nice! but theres still one problem, now it only displays F:

Comment: F : 5
F : 29
F : 38
F : 24
F : 12
F : 17

Comment: Can you post the code generating this output?
EDIT:Oh I am sorry. You already posted this part

Comment: i think the problem lies in system.print, cause for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++){
   System.out.println(grades[i+'a'] + " : " + counts[i]);
  }

Comment: it prints all Bs instead of Fs

Comment: Look at my change. Not grades[i+'A'] but just i+'A'

Comment: So yes, the problem is the system.print.
It should look like: System.out.println((i+'A') + ":"+ counts[i]);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121524/discussion-between-andreas-lackner-and-p-kwong).

Comment: fixed it with the simplest method, just printing char(i+a)

Comment: oh sorry, andres, yes hahahah same answer as urs. Thanks!